# Show from Action Menu the Res_partner Form with partner information corresponding to the current User

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

In order to show this form view :

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="program_viewform">
            <field name="name">My Program</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form>
                    <separator string="My Program " />
                <field name="projects_ids"  nolabel="True"/>
                    <separator string="submitted Tasks" />
                    <field name="submission_task_ids" nolabel="True"/>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```

I created this action :

```xml
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="myprogram_action">
        <field name="name">My Program</field>
        <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="form_view_id" ref="training_program_management.program_viewform"/>
            <field name="domain">[('id','=',user.id.partner_id)]</field>
          <field name="view_mode">form</field>
      </record>
```

and this Menu :

```
<menuitem name="My Program" id="program_menu" sequence="5"
              parent="training_program_management.menu" action="training_program_management.myprogram_action"/>
```

What I need is to show the record of res_partner corresponding to the current User, knowing that res.users contains a Many2one Field "Partner_id".
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

This is tested for odoo 8 but it can probably be adapted for odoo 10 or at least help you :

Change `<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="myprogram_action">` to `<record model="ir.actions.server" id="myprogram_action">`

Then add (yes, old API is on purpose, it doesn't work with the new API, for odoo 8 that is)

```
<field name='model_id' ref='base.model_res_partner'/>
<field name="code">
    action = self._action_open_user_res_partner(cr, uid)
</field>
```

Create a model extending `res.partner` in your module, add (more old API ...  also I didn't find a way to use `ref()`)

```
@api.model
def _action_open_user_res_partner(self, cr, uid):
    return {
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        # Since this is a constant, you can use a global to hold the value for 'view_id'
        'view_id': int(self.pool['ir.ui.view'].search(cr, uid, 
                                                   [('name', '=', 'My Program')])[0]),
        'res_model': 'res.partner',
        'res_id': int(self.pool['res.users'].browse(cr, uid, [uid])[0].partner_id),
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'context': {}
    }
```

Adapting this to odoo 10 probably involves using the new API instead of the old one. This means `self.pool` should be `self.env` or `env`, and that you don't need `cr` and `uid` anymore. You can use `user` variable instead of uid in the function returning (well actually it could be used for odoo 8 too, but since `uid` is needed anyway...).

On the other hand, [the documentation for odoo 10 about actions](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/actions.html#server-actions-ir-actions-server) strongly suggests you'd still need to use the old API for this, except for `model` replacing `self`.

So you should first try something like this for odoo 10 :

```
<field name='model_id' ref='base.model_res_partner'/>
<field name="code">
    action = model._action_open_user_res_partner(cr, uid)
</field>
```

The function in the model is still the same, since we still use the old API.

If it doesn't work, you should try with the new API (get rid of cr, uid)

Answer (score 0):

The code bellow, worked perfectly for me, Thank you alot for your help:

```
<record model="ir.actions.server" id="myprogram_action">
        <field name="name">My Program</field>
            <field name='model_id' ref='base.model_res_partner'/>
             <field name="state">code</field>
            <field name="code">
                action = {
                    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                    'name': 'My Program',
                    'view_mode': 'form',
                    'view_type': 'form',
                    'res_model': 'res.partner',
                    'nodestroy': 'true',
                    'res_id': int(env['res.users'].browse(env.user.partner_id.id)),
                    'views': [(False, 'form')],
                    'view_id': 'ref="training_program_management.program_viewform"',
                }
            </field>
        </record>
```

Still have a small problem thou, i have two FormViews for res.partner, this line doesn't seem to show the desired View:

```
'view_id': 'ref="training_program_management.program_viewform"',
```

It shows me The First FormView That i've inherited.
My training_program_management.program_viewform :

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="program_viewform">
            <field name="name">My Program</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form>
                    <separator string="My Program " />
                <field name="projects_ids"  nolabel="True"/>
                    <separator string="submitted Tasks" />
                    <field name="submission_task_ids" nolabel="True"/>



                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```

What can i do to show this View Instead Of the inherited one ?